# Trying to find the issue in my approach to definite integral question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is in relation to the following question here:
[Difficult integral problem about $\ln(n+1)/n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818211/difficult-integral-problem-about-lnn1-n)

In the above problem, I tried the following approach

$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^{kn} = 1 + x^n + x^{2n}+... + x^{n^2}$$

Using GP formula

$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^{kn} = \frac{x^{n(n+1)} - 1}{x^n - 1}$$

Now, using this in the integral, we can write it as

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{(n+1)x^n - \frac{x^{n(n+1)} - 1}{x^n - 1} }{x^{n(n+1)} - 1}\text{dx}$$

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{(n+1)x^n}{x^{n(n+1)} - 1} dx - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^n-1}dx$$

Now using the substitution for $u = x^{n+1} \implies du = (n+1)x^n dx$ in the first term

$$I = I_1 - I_2 = \int_0^1\frac{du}{u^n-1} - \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^n-1} = 0$$

Where have I gone wrong? This has been on my mind for hours now, and I just can't seem to catch the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraically this is "fine." The problem is the final integrals do not converge. Subtracting infinities is bound to cause issues like this. Remember you can only split integrals up if at most one piece diverges to infinity (or multiple do but they diverge to the same signed infinity) at which point you simply get the signed infinity in question.

Comment: Aah that makes sense - thanks!